# Running Python Function from PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell

I have a .py file with a script.

I want to run it from the PowerShell. I can do it by writing:

```
C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe "X:\Data\_Private\Data\test.py"
```

However I want to pass some arguments to the script. Thus, I set all script as a `main(argument1, argument2)` function. It looks like this:

```
def main(argument1, argument2):
    def Hello(argument1, argument2):
        print("Hi " + argument1 + " and " + argument2 + "!")
```

And the rest of the script continues.

Maybe someone could tell me how can I run that script from PowerShell in one line and passing arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```
import sys

def Hello(argument1, argument2):
    print("Hi " + argument1 + " " + argument2 + "!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Hello(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

And from PowerShell:

```
python test.py 1 2
```

Of course you probably want to check your argv indices are within range.

Comment: Thank  you for the solution, it works !! However, I have some packages in my script that don't want to load, e.g. {from monthdelta import monthdelta} or {from openpyxl import Workbook} . I get the error: <pre>ImportError: No module named 'monthdelta'<code>. However, {import pandas as pd} or several other packages don't cause the same problem. Maybe you could help on this as well?

Comment: Only just saw your comment. Try typing on the powershell prompt: pip install monthdelta

Comment: It worked after I tried to run by writing full path to python (C:/..../python.exe). However, I encountered another error. I have a logger in the script, that send an e-mail when script raises an error. Even though, script runs well and delivers the correct result, I get an error, that argument was not passed to the function (without the argument I wouldn't get desired result). Maybe, you what might be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the main funciton should looks like this:

```
import sys

def hello(argument1,argument2):
    print("Hi " + argument1 " and " + argument2 "!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg1 = sys.argv[1]
    arg2 = sys.argv[2]
    hello(arg1, arg2)
```

You only define the function main but you never call it.

Read for example here more about main: [main](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)
Read more about sys.argv: [sys_argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html)

Comment: Thank  you for the solution, it works !! However, I have some packages in my script that don't want to load, e.g. from monthdelta import monthdelta or from openpyxl import Workbook . I get the error: ImportError: No module named 'monthdelta'. However, import pandas as pd or several other packages don't cause the same problem. Maybe you could help on this as well?

Comment: Did you install the modules? You have to install them (pip install <modulename>.

Comment: I have all modules installed and it worked after I tried to run by writing full path to python (C:/..../python.exe) to PowerShell instead of 'python'. However, I encountered another error. I have a logger in the script, that send an e-mail when script raises an error. Even though, script runs well and delivers the correct result, I get an error, that argument was not passed to the function (without the argument I wouldn't get desired result). Maybe, you what might be an issue?